# JS call nested async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to use async/await in this code below.

At the `if/else` part, it validates correctly but the nested function doesn't get called.

The code just stops after the `if/else` completes.

Could someone shine some light on this? Thanks.

```
async function initBot () {

  await botui.message.bot({
    content: `Do you have any questions?`
  })

  let q1 = await botui.action.button({
    action: [{
      text: 'Yes',
      value: 'yes'
    }, {
      text: 'No',
      value: 'no'
    }]
  })

  // This is where it's stuck

  if (q1.value === 'yes') {
      askQuestion()
  } else {
      endConvo()
  }

  let endConvo = async () => {
    await botui.message.bot({
      content: `END`
    })
  }

  let askQuestion = async () => {
    await botui.message.bot({
      content: `What's your questions?`
    })
  }
}

export default initBot
```

Answer (score 0):

try await before the async functions

```
if (q1.value === 'yes') {
      await askQuestion()
  } else {
      await endConvo()
  }
```

since askQuestion() and endConvo() are async functions, your program exits without waiting for them to complete

Comment: the function wasn't called ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah blimey.

It's just the case of declaring those functions `endConvo` and `askQuestion` **before** using it in the `if/else`.

Using ESlint gave me this clue.